# Geometric Interpretation of Simultaneous Primal and Dual LP Infeasibility

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

There are examples of linear programming (LP) problems where both the primal and dual problems are infeasible.  For example,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\min_x && x \\
&\ \ \text{s.t.} &&0\cdot x\leq -1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
On the other hand, there are examples of linear programming problems where the primal is infeasible and the dual is unbounded. For example,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\min_x && x \\
&\ \ \text{s.t.} && x\geq 1 \\
& && x\leq 0 \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
I am wondering: is there any geometric interpretation of this phenomenon? Is there some geometric difference between those infeasible LPs with infeasible duals and those infeasible LPs with unbounded duals?